# C# Load .txt file and show in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, import

so what I'm trying to do is load a .txt file and once the .txt file is loaded it will show the contents from the .txt file in a listView.

Here is my load code.

```
        List<String> proxies = new List<string>();
    private void loadProxiesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadProxies();
    }

    private void loadProxies()
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
            ofd.Title = "Load Proxies";
            var dialogResult = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                proxies = new List<string>();
                Parallel.ForEach(System.IO.File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName), (line, _, lineNumber) =>
                {
                    if (line.Contains(":"))
                    {
                        //loadedCombo.Add(line);
                        proxies.Add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Hmm, thats not a combolist - please try again");
                    }
                });
            }

            txt_proxies.Text = "Proxies Loaded: " + proxies.Count.ToString();

        }));
    }
```

and I'm wanting it to show in the listView which is named "proxyView".

So what I'm trying to say it, I can get the .txt to load and it changes the count but it's not adding the contents from the .txt file into the listview.

Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code to add items to `ListView`?

Comment: Yeah this is what I can't get, How would i do that?

Comment: Why are you using `this.Invoke`? and why are you using `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: that isn't relevant and wouldn't resolve my problem

Comment: Use `proxyView.Items.Add(line)`

Comment: I added proxyView.Items.Add(line); and now im getting this error An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'proxyView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: That's why @Yacoub asked you that question.

Comment: then what code to use to resolve the issue?

Comment: You can use it without `Invoke`, Use it without `Parallel.For`, instead use a simple for, foreach or `IEnumerable.ForEach` extension. You don't need a `Parallel.For`.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean

Comment: Do you use `loadProxies` in a thread?

Comment: no its not used in a thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an item to a [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use [`yourListView.Items.Add(text)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttzhk9y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example:

```
private void loadProxies()
{ 
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
    ofd.Title = "Load Proxies";
    var dialogResult = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName))
        {
            if (line.Contains(":"))
                proxyView.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on comments it seems you don't need to use `Invoke` because you are not using the method in a different thread than UI thread and also it seems you don't need to use `Parallel.For`

Comment: got this error Error The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Add `using System.IO;` or simply use `System.IO.File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName)` See the update

Comment: Excellent answer!